# How is the distance between 'cells' calculated when justify-content: space-evenly & there is a column-gap?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

When `justify-content: start/center/end` and there is a `column-gap`, it's easy to predict the positioning - the `column-gap` stays. When `justify-content: space-between`, its presence isn't seen.

How is the distance between 'cells' calculated when `justify-content: space-evenly` & there is a `column-gap`?

```css
#grid-container {
    display: grid;
    width: 800px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    grid-template-columns: 150px 150px 150px;
    column-gap: 50px;
    justify-items: start;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

#grid-container > div:nth-child(1) {
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid black 5px;
    margin: 8px;
}

#grid-container > div:nth-child(2) {
    padding: 3px;
    border: solid black 10px;
    margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid-container">
  <div style="background-color: blue;">I am div 1.</div>
  <div style="background-color: red;">I am div2.</div>
  <div style="background-color: green;">I am div 3.</div>  
</div>
```

P.s. My next question would be the same but concerning `space-around`.

Comment: IMHO, grid-gap would be overwritten or deleted, unless it turns out to be a minimal space to preserve. Did the doc mention anything?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Doesn't look overwritten or deleted in my code

Comment: There is a CSS Grid specification, can you search for the answer there? [CSS Grid spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#intro)

Comment: if that grid-gap remains through different actual browsers, you may think that  it follows the w3c recommandation standards, else, the w3c.org remains the reference if the spec is not anymore in a draft state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take an illustration of `space-evenly` which is the easiest one since this alignment should produce equal space between all the elements and the sides.

```css
#grid-container {
  display: grid;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin:5px;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  column-gap: 50px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background:repeating-linear-gradient(to right,transparent 0 8px,grey 0 10px);
}

#grid-container> * {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid-container">
  <div style="background-color: blue;">I am div 1.</div>
  <div style="background-color: red;">I am div2.</div>
  <div style="background-color: green;">I am div 3.</div>
</div>

<div id="grid-container" style="column-gap:0">
  <div style="background-color: blue;">I am div 1.</div>
  <div style="background-color: red;">I am div2.</div>
  <div style="background-color: green;">I am div 3.</div>
</div>
```

When there is no gap we can clearly see a space of `50px` which is `500px - 3*100px = 200px` divided by 4.

With the gap we have a space of `25px` on the sides and `75px` in the middle and we can logically conclude that the `75px` is `50px + 25px` where `50px` is our gap.

It's now clear that the calculation of the space if first done without the gap that we omit for the free space calculation then we add them. In our first case the free space is equal to `500px - 3*100px - 2*50px = 100px` that we divide by 4 to get `25px`. We put the `25px` between our elements and on each side and finally we add back our gap in the middle.

Same logic apply with `space-around`:

```css
#grid-container {
  display: grid;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin:5px;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  column-gap: 50px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background:repeating-linear-gradient(to right,transparent 0 8px,grey 0 10px);
}

#grid-container> * {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid-container">
  <div style="background-color: blue;">I am div 1.</div>
  <div style="background-color: red;">I am div2.</div>
  <div style="background-color: green;">I am div 3.</div>
</div>

<div id="grid-container" style="column-gap:0">
  <div style="background-color: blue;">I am div 1.</div>
  <div style="background-color: red;">I am div2.</div>
  <div style="background-color: green;">I am div 3.</div>
</div>
```

Without gap, the free space is `200px` that we divide into 3 to get `66.67px`. Two of them are placed in the middle and one is divided by 2 to get `33.33px` on each side.

With the gap, the free space is `100px`. Divided by 3 we get `33.33px` that we also divide by 2 to get `16.67px`. So we will have `16.67px` on the sides and `83.33px` in the middle.

---

The logic behind this is to ensure that we have at least a space between our element equal to the gap defined that's why the gap is not considered when doing the free space calculation and the alignment can only **increase** the gap and never decrease it.

> Note: Additional spacing may be added between tracks due to justify-content/align-content. See § 11.1 Grid Sizing Algorithm. **This space effectively increases the size of the gutters**. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#gutters)</sup>

Also

> free space
>
> Equal to the available grid space minus the sum of the base sizes of all the grid tracks **(including gutters)**, floored at zero. If available grid space is indefinite, the free space is indefinite as well. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#algo-terms)</sup>